# Iterating through each token of a line within a file in C

Tags: c, file, token, tokenize

I am trying to parse through each token within each line of a file. But I am getting an infinite loop in the inner while loop. Why is this? It's not because of the "true" condition as I have break statements within the while loop. I think I am not correctly
checking when I get to the end of a line.

```
char currentLine[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH + 1]; // + 1 for terminating char

    while (true) {
        if (fgets(currentLine, MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH, inputFilePointer) == EOF ) {
            break;
        } else { // we need to parse the currentLine
            // check if the currentLine is too long
            if (strlen(currentLine) > MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH) {
                // print to the file that the currentLine being parsed it too long
                printf(
                        "WARNING: currentLine is too long and must be <= 256 characters\n");
                continue; // move on to next line in input file
            } else { // currentLine has valid length
                while (true) {
                    // iterate through each token within the currentLine and parse the token
                    char *currentToken = strtok(currentLine, " $,\t");
                    printf("currentToken = %s", currentToken);
                                    // do something with currentToken

                    if (currentToken == NULL || *currentToken == '#') {
                        break; // <== ERROR This break statement is never getting hit WHY?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

If you make `MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH` a defined constant, then your `WARNING` message should really reference it rather than hard-coding the value `256`. But that's not the actual problem.

The code needs to be

```
char currentLine[MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH + 1]; // + 1 for terminating char

while (true) {
    if (fgets(currentLine, MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH, inputFilePointer) == EOF ) {
        break;
    } else { // we need to parse the currentLine
        // check if the currentLine is too long
        if (strlen(currentLine) > MAXIMUM_LINE_LENGTH) {
            // print to the file that the currentLine being parsed it too long
            printf( "WARNING: currentLine is too long and must be <= 256 characters\n");
            continue; // move on to next line in input file
        } else { // currentLine has valid length
            char *currentToken = strtok(currentLine, " $,\t");
            while(currentToken != NULL && *currentToken != '#') {
                // iterate through each token within the currentLine and parse the token
                printf("currentToken = %s", currentToken);
                    // do something with currentToken
                currentToken = strtok(NULL, " $,\t"); // get next token
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on? The `strtok` function actually "remembers" the string you asked for, and puts a `nul` character where it found a token; next time you call it, it will start "at the next point", and scan for the next token. So it actually overwrites your initial string, and slowly "chomps" through it.

In your original code, you kept passing a "new" string to `strtok`, so it never got past the first token. It needs to be passed `NULL` to keep chomping away (as in the above example).

Note also that I used the fact that we need two versions of the call to `strtok` to clean up the structure of your code a little bit - now the condition of the `while` is the terminating condition (since the first call to `strtok` happens before we enter the while loop).

Answer (score 0):

you should call the `strtok()` with `NULL` from your second iteration onwards.

Like this

```
  token = strtok(input, tok);
  while (token ! = NULL ) {
        token = strtok(NULL, tok);
  /*do token processing*/
  }
```

see this example for details:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm